# Fastest way to check if either one of two numbers is odd using bitwise operations

Tags: numbers, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and, bitwise-xor

I came up with the following code (written in Solidity assembly):

```
let z := xor(and(x, 1), and(y, 1))
```

Where `x` and `y` are of type `int256` (they are signed and can have negative values). `z` is the result, and it's equal to 1 when either of `x` and `y` are odd, and 0 when both are either odd or even.

The question is whether there is any algorithm that is faster than the one I wrote above?

Comment: It depends a lot on how your system optimizes.  If it knows that `and(x,1)` only needs the low bit of `a`, then it might be able to just look at the lowest byte/word of `x` instead of all 256 bits, and then do the `xor` of a single byte/word instead of 256 bits.  If it doesn't know that, and has to process all 256 bits every time regardless, then `and(xor(x,y), 1)` might be better.

Comment: Or if booleans are handled more efficiently than `int256`, you could consider `xor(and(x,1) == 1, and(y, 1) == 1)`.

Comment: Thanks, @NateEldredge! Happy to mark your solutions/ explanations as the accepted answer, if you post them below.